# Display / Hide a child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in a React render function:

```
<div>
    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 1</div>
        <HiddenBox />
    </InnerBox>

    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 2</div>
        <HiddenBox />
    </InnerBox>

    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 3</div>
        <HiddenBox />
    </InnerBox>
</div>
```

I would like each of the `<HiddenBox />` elements to be hidden until the `<InnerBox>` element is clicked on. Any other child elements of `<InnerBox>` should be displayed at all times.

I currently have the following function in my `InnerBox` class:

```
handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        button_state: "clicked"
    })
}
```

And my render function of the `InnerBox` class looks something like this:

```
return (
    <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.children}</div>
)
```

However, I am a bit confused as to where exactly the code would go to toggle the display of the `HiddenBox` element for the specific `InnerBox` that was clicked on.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you could resolve this by updating the rendering of `<InnerBox/>` in this way:

```
<div>
    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 1</div>
    </InnerBox>

    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 2</div>
    </InnerBox>

    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 3</div>
    </InnerBox>
</div>
```

You could then update the `render()` function of `<InnerBox/>` like so:

```
render() {

    const { button_state } = this.state;
    const isButtonStateClicked = button_state === 'clicked';

    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
    { this.props.children }
    { isButtonStateClicked && <HiddenBox /> }
    </div>)
}
```

Finally, you'd update `handdleClick()` in this way to achieve to hide/show toggle behaviour:

```
handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        button_state: this.state.button_state === 'clicked' : '' : 'clicked'
    })
}
```

Comment: A problem with this is that this hides or shows all of the children. I only want to toggle the <HiddenBox /> element.

Comment: Sorry, some of my original question was not showing properly because I had it in tags. I fixed that now. Also, I think this updated solution will not work because <HiddenBox /> is a child of <InnerBox>.

Comment: @kojow7 not a problem re updates - if you update your jsx so the `<InnerBox/>` components are rendered like `    <InnerBox>
        <div>Box 3</div>
    </InnerBox>`  does that work for you?

Comment: Ah, yes, I think that might work, because then I can just pass that data as props instead from the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

To toggle hide and show.

```js
export default class InnerBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    buttonClicked: false
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonClicked: !this.state.buttonClicked
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.children}
        {this.state.buttonClicked && <HiddenBox />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this any different from Dacre Denny's answer?

Comment: you can toggle hide and show. This is a more compact and frequently used pattern.