# How to display unknown child elements in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to manipulate some li-tags in a certain way, however, I get 
these tags from a third-party script, which I have no control over. The third-party just provides the ul-tag and loads all the other tags afterwards inside the ul-tag. Inside the tag are some div-tags until the li-tags occur.

My goal is to get the li-tags and then display just a certain amount per click().

I am not really certain how to tackle the problem, thus my posts lacks a minimal example.

The "this.props.children" approach has been always "undefined" until now, I guess the li-tags are loaded later on, but even the ComponentDidMount() does not seem to fix the problem.

```
<ul>
 <div>
  ...
   <div>
    <li />
    <li />
    ....
    <li />
   </div>
 </div>
</ul>
```

I already checked out the following post:
[Display / Hide a child component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999329/display-hide-a-child-component-in-react)
However, apparently the hidden-elemnts are already known before the building process and not afterwards.

Provided third-party code:

```
<script src="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<ul class="juicer-feed" data-feed-id="PRIVATE ID"></ul>
```

Comment: What third party library are you using? You should look into the API and determine what methods you have available to see what could be used to [integrate the third party library into your react app](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).

Comment: DO it in componentDidUpdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because you are using a third party lib it deals with the DOM directly not with React that is why the container Component doesn't consider them as children the were added later, so I suggest whether you render those li tags within the Component itself if possible and if not you can use vanilla javaScript to manipulate the DOM and do whatever you want that if you have no control of the third party library.

Comment: Well, the manipulation afterwards with VanillaJS works. It seems to me a bit messy however. Thanks for the advise anyways.